# Does June 2022 LaTeX require use of padmanagement-testphase and hyperref key pdfproducer?

Tags: hyperref, pdf, metadata, hyperxmp

Are either of the commented-out lines below still needed with the June 2022 release of LaTeX?

Specifically:

1. Is the `\RequirePackage{pdfmanagement-testphase}` automatically invoked by `\DocumentMetadata{testphase=Phase=II`....`}?`
2. Is the `hyperref` key `pdfproducer` superfluous?

```
   %\RequirePackage{pdfmanagement-testphase}
   \DocumentMetadata{%
     testphase=Phase-II,
     uncompress,
     pdfstandard=a-2u}
     
   \documentclass{memoir}
     
   \usepackage{hyperxmp}
   \usepackage{hyperref}
   \hypersetup{
     unicode,
     pdfapart=2, pdfaconformance=u,
     pdftitle={A Book},
     pdfauthor={A Writer},pdfcreator={Hmself},
     pdfdate={\today},
     pdflang={en},pdfmetalang={en},
     pdfpubtype={Book},
     pdfsubject={math},
     pdfkeywords={math,mathematics},
     %pdfproducer=pdfTeX-1.40.24, %why needed ??
    }
    
    \begin{document}
    \mainmatter
      \chapter{Equations}
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

The pdfmanagement in the `pdfmanagement-testphase` package is still required and used but it is now loaded automatically by `\DocumentMetadata`, so you don't have to load it manually (but it doesn't harm either).

You should set the language (but en-EN is the default anyway) in `\DocumentMetadata` with the lang key, and you neither need unicode nor the pdfa-settings in hyperref. I need to check the pdfproducer setting.

```
\DocumentMetadata{%
     testphase=phase-II,
     uncompress,
     lang=en,
     pdfstandard=a-2u}

   \documentclass{memoir}

   \usepackage{hyperxmp}
   \usepackage{hyperref}
   \hypersetup{
     pdftitle={A Book},
     pdfauthor={A Writer},pdfcreator={Hmself},
     pdfdate={\today},
     pdfmetalang={en},
     pdfpubtype={Book},
     pdfsubject={math},
     pdfkeywords={math,mathematics},
     pdfproducer=pdfTeX-1.40.24, %why needed ??
    }

    \begin{document}
    \mainmatter
      \chapter{Equations}
    \end{document}
```

Be aware that memoir is a complicated class and that it is not garantied that it will always be directly compatible with testphase code.